# Why CreateWindowEx() function returns always 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, activex

I am trying to implement Windows Messaging in C# **in order to communicate a HTML page with a regular exe**. What I need to do is to create a new window with a specific class name and window name, so that other processes can send Windows Messages to my Activex application.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
           WindowStylesEx dwExStyle,
           string lpClassName,
           string lpWindowName,
           WindowStyles dwStyle,
           int x,
           int y,
           int nWidth,
           int nHeight,
           IntPtr hWndParent,
           IntPtr hMenu,
           IntPtr hInstance,
           IntPtr lpParam);


            IntPtr temp = CreateWindowEx(0, "privateclassname", "privatewindowname",
                WindowStyles.WS_CHILD | WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This is what I' ve been trying but temp always get 0 instead of a proper window handle. What is wrong with this piece of code? I suspect *hWndParent* parameter. A give it 0 because I don' t know the parent' s handle, or it even exists. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the CharSet correct? I don't remember what the default is but you might want to set it to Unicode...

Comment: Did you call RegisterClass for "privateclassname".  Did you check the return code from that function?

Comment: I set it but the problem persists. `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in WS_CHILD for a window style flag, but you are not passing a parent window handle (you are passing 0/NULL).  Try removing the WS_CHILD style.

Also, see my comment about calling RegisterClass above (if that applies).

Comment: You were right this was a mistake. I corrected it but I still need to call RegisterClass as you said. Can you provide me an example? Thank you so much

Comment: Here's why this is a hard problem in C#.  RegisterClass maps the window class name to a C function that serves as the WndProc for windows of that class. That means you have to declare a WNDCLASS struct in C#.  The WNDCLASS instance has an lpfnWndProc member - which is a pointer to a C function.  Good luck with that in C#.  (Although I won't be surprised if this can be done).

Comment: I strongly suspect you are going about this in the wrong way. But it's unclear from your post if your code is the ActiveX control or the regular EXE that you speak of.  I would strongly recommend writing the HWND communication mechanism in a C/C++ dll, then providing simple helper functions from the DLL to the C# code can P/Invoke to for creating and managing the window.  In theory if you can create a window from a C/C++ dll, a C# forms app will do the message pumping required as a result of calling Application.Run

Comment: I understand what you mean. You are right and I decided to write this code in C++. Thank you again :)

Comment: @selbie It can be done quite readily with `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`. But I don't disagree without your basic advice.